# AWS DynamoDB: how to remove a value from a column?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my AWS project, I use DynamoDB to store data. For some items, I want to update them by removing a value from a column, like the follwing example:

```
      |  Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3
      |--------|--------|--------
from: | value1 | value2 | value3
      |--------|--------|--------

      |  Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3
      |--------|--------|--------
to:   | value1 | value2 |
      |--------|--------|--------
```

So I tried with an update operation, but I got an error telling me that the value for `Col3` should not be empty.

Then I tried with 2 operations (delete, then add) but to make sure that I always have consistent data, I tried to put them in a write transaction operation. But I also got an error: `"ValidationException: Transaction request cannot include multiple operations on one item"`.

One more thing: since `Col3` is an index, I really want to remove the value instead of replacing it by another one, in order to save space and to reduce costs.

So is there a way to update that item by removing the value for `Col3` while being sure that I always have consistent data?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the `remove` operator, so you can update the item by removing the value for `Col3`:

```js
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    var params = {
      TableName: 'test',
      Key: { 'id' : '3' },
      UpdateExpression: 'remove Col3'
    };

    var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    documentClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) console.log(err);
       else console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Exactly. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE